# PointCloud2 orientation Problem? [I need some help!]

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All

I am having some problems with the orientation of ht PointCloud2 image published.  I could tell it's not the problem with the TF because the axis looks correct according to the Rviz. Do you guys know where-else did I forgot to change the orientation? thank you in advance!

---

The problem is, as you could see from the image below. The TF transform is correct. But then the  PointCloud2 looks like it has some "roll yaw pitch" error;  the clouds should be on the ground plane; it shouldn't be flying at the mid air.

[image: image description][image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66556/pointcloud2-orientation-problem?--%5Bi-need-some-help!%5D/) by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2013-07-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2013-07-03**:
You didn't say what the problem was...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Gazer,

Just a guess, but I suspect your problem is actually due to the TF being wrong. Check out the REP here:
http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html

For robots it's conventional to put the X+ as the 'forward' direction, but there's a lot of camera stuff that uses Z+ as the forward direction instead.

Cheers,
Gavin

---

Originally posted by [Gav](https://answers.ros.org/users/3961/gav/) with karma: 478 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0